# Mailto link in paragraph creating line break in Talkback on Android

Tags: android, html, accessibility, mailto

I'm having this problem with a mailto link inside a paragraph, on Android using Talkback voice over:

[image from Android](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nIuzD.png)

```
<section class="col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12 text-center">
    <p>Lorem ipsum sit dolor amet <a href="mailto:email@email.com" data-rel="external">email</a> consectetur adipiscing elit. Vestibulum faucibus est lobortis.</p>
</section>
```

In Talkback, when you tap and the voice over reads the text, it stops before "email," then you have to tap on "consectetur..." and that gets read as if it were a new section.

Essentially, the email link splits up a single paragraph into two sections. I want the paragraph to be read/viewed by Talkback as one paragraph.

Any insight appreciated.

Comment: I think the behavior of the touch action that you are testing is doing exactly what it is supposed to do.  If you do a three finger swipe down does it read the entire paragraph?

Comment: @JimKiely Is the default behavior to split up paragraph at anchors? Three finger swipe does nothing. One or two finger swipe brings up the green dotted outline (see image).